# Computer slow on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (was fast for 30 days after installation)

Tags: dell, performance

I found a Dell XPS M1730 in my box of computers and wanted to bring it back to life with Linux. 30 days ago, I installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa) and was impressed with the speed of Ubuntu. I could go onto YouTube in just 1 second and load a normal webpage as fast as I can snap my finger. But after 30 days I am experiencing slowness:

- Firefox takes 4 seconds to load
- Settings take 3 seconds

If you have any idea on how to restore the speed, I would really appreciate it. It is not the internet because other computers in my house are fast.

Specifications:

[image: Specs]

Comment: That machine shipped with a pair of hard drives spinning at 5400rpm. However, based on the disk capacity, I would assume you've upgraded to an SSD. Is this correct? Have you made changes to the power settings? Have you installed any browser extensions or Gnome extensions? How much swap space do you have available regularly? Is the system always connected to power, or do you use it on battery and notice the slowness at that time? ... There are hundreds of questions that can be asked to try and find the root cause of a performance degradation 

Comment: Yes SSD. Turn off after 5 mins on AC power. No browser extensions. Battery dead so on AC power.

Comment: Is this issue still present? Also, you can consider switching to Xubuntu or Lubuntu, which demand less resources.

Comment: From the self-accepted answer: 'This was just a problem with my computer.' this appears to be an isolated issue that went away. Closed as non-reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was just a problem with my computer. If this issue persists on your computer, then install an older version of Ubuntu or a lighter Linux distro (example: Lubuntu).